# issues with VTK's Python bindings

Tags: python, vtk

First of all, I did successfully compile and install VTK, as it can be seen from the following message

```
Installed /tmp/yifli/lib/python2.6/site-packages/VTK-5.8.0-py2.6.egg
```

However , when I try to import vtk, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/yifli/lib/python2.6/site-packages/VTK-5.8.0-py2.6.egg/vtk/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    __helper.refine_import_err('qvtk', 'vtkQtPython', exc)
  File "/tmp/yifli/lib/python2.6/site-packages/VTK-5.8.0-py2.6.egg/vtk/__helper.py", line 32, in refine_import_err
    raise LinkError, str(exc)
vtk.__helper.LinkError: /tmp/yifli/lib/vtk-5.8/libQVTK.so.5.8: undefined symbol: _ZN19QAbstractProxyModel11setItemDataERK11QModelIndexRK4QMapIi8QVariantE
```

And all the tests failed when I run 'ctest -R Python' in the building directory.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you built with Qt support, QVTK is the Qt widget(s) to support VTK render window. You have an issue with an undefined symbol from Qt (QAbstractProxyModel), likely due to compiling with a newer Qt than that available when you import the VTK python module. Running,

```
ldd /tmp/yifli/lib/vtk-5.8/libQVTK.so.5.8
```

would show you which Qt library it is trying to link to.